# Use variable in WScript.Run

Tags: powershell, vbscript, wsh

The following works fine:

**VBScript**

```vb
Script = "C:\Users\bob\Downloads\Logon scripts\Script.ps1"
Dim oSHELL
Set oSHELL = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oSHELL.Run "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -File ""C:\Users\bob\Downloads\Logon scripts\Script.ps1""", 0, True
Set oSHELL = Nothing
```

When I'm trying to put the path to the script in a variabla, it's not working:

```vb
oSHELL.Run "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -File ""Script""", 0, True
oSHELL.Run "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -File""" & Script & """", 0, True
```

**Script.ps1**

```bsh
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Test MessageBox", "Information")
```

How is it possible to have `WScript` use the variable correctly?

Comment: The second example you are missing a space after `-File`. Apart from that it should work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from a slight typo in your second example *(missing space after `-File`)* 
Currently, it will execute like

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -File"C:\Users\bob\Downloads\Logon scripts\Script.ps1"
```

and produce an error, which you haven't documented in the question.

I can't see why this wouldn't work.

```vb
Dim oSHELL: Set oSHELL = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim Script: Script = "C:\Users\bob\Downloads\Logon scripts\Script.ps1"
Call oSHELL.Run("powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -File """ & Script & """", 0, True)
```

It's equivalent to;

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -File "C:\Users\bob\Downloads\Logon scripts\Script.ps1"
```

Comment: You are correct, it does work. Must have been the typo. Thank you for clarifying.